# Popup menu. Выпадающий список, сдвинутый всторону

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Есть ли возможность задать у [select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/) `y-offset` аналогично тому, как это можно сделать для [menus](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/) `offset-y`?

Comment: Насколько мне известно штатного функционала для этого нет(могу ошибатся), нужно делать свой костыль

Comment: @Vearodev могли бы подсказать, как это можно было бы сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например при помощи CSS.

```css
.v-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```